# pagination is applied not working in django

Tags: python, django, error-handling, pagination

in my custom templates pagination is applied on it. the list that show on page is much bigger than i used pagination on it. the limit to display the list is wroking properly but when i click on the next button than it go on the else condition.

views.py :-

```
@csrf_exempt
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        getchoice = request.POST['userchoice']
        getfirstdate = request.POST['firstdate']
        getseconddate = request.POST['seconddate']


        if getchoice == '0':
            getdata = applicationform.objects.filter(date__gte=getfirstdate , date__lte=getseconddate)
            ##### PAGINATION
            searchpagination = Paginator(getdata ,5)
            page = request.GET.get('searchpage')
            try:
                searchcontacts = searchpagination.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                searchcontacts = searchpagination.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                searchcontacts = searchpagination.page(searchpagination.num_pages)  

            if getdata:
                return render_to_response('registration/search_page.html', {'getdata':getdata ,'getchoice':getchoice ,'searchcontacts': searchcontacts})    
            else:
                return HttpResponse('NO ITEMS FOUND ON THIS DATE')
    else :  
            return render_to_response('registration/search_page.html')
```

custom template:-

```
{% if searchcontacts.has_previous %}
<a href="?searchpage={{ searchcontacts.previous_page_number }}">PREVIOUS</a>
{% endif %}
{% if searchcontacts.has_next %}    
<a href="?searchpage={{ searchcontacts.next_page_number }}">NEXT</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on `NEXT` will be `GET` request and hence it is going in `else` section.

To continue search for next page, either you need to store search parameters in the session or pass it through url. And then use that in `filter()` query.